# How to add listener to optionsGroup in Java Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

How can i add event listener to OptionGroup in java vaadin.

```
            OptionGroup group = new OptionGroup("Star Rating");
            group.addItem("1 star");
            group.addItem("2 star");
            group.addItem("3 star");
            group.addItem("4 star");
            group.addItem("5 star");
            group.addStyleName("horizontal");
            group.setSizeUndefined();
```

In the above example i want to add listener to on selecting value in radion button so that i can store value in mysql for star rating. How can i implement that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter? Additionally, you may want to check out the [RatingStars add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/ratingstars) which offers some _sweet eye-candy_.

Comment: @Morfic rating star is the one i need as i am using vaadin but in my case i need to store the star value in mysql as my page is dynamic and content is generated based on search. How can i customize it for star value in mysql so that afer selecting star value i should be able to pop average star value.

Comment: I believe you're trying to do something similar to the [online demo](http://teemu.virtuallypreinstalled.com/RatingStars/) which means you can get some inspiration from [the sources](https://github.com/tehapo/RatingStars/blob/master/demo/org/vaadin/teemu/ratingstars/RatingStarsDemo.java), more specifically the `private void populateTable()` method, with a handler similar to what **Andre Schild** has posted in his answer. Let me know if you have further issues.

Comment: Yes but in demo likes are stored anywhere. when i refresh the page all like goes away and random likes come in the page. How can i store star selected information somewhere and color them based on average score.

Comment: You get the value that the user selected by clicking on the star in your `ValueChangeListener`, store it in your MySQL DB as you said, then based on your other stored values calculate the average and set the value of the other _pop-up_ rating. Is there anything I'm missing?!

Comment: actually i am newbie in this area .....   can u pls mail me any example where i can use ValueChangeListener.

Answer (score 2):

On most input components you can add a `ValueChangeListener`.

According to the [javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/OptionGroup.html) the OptionGroup has this as well.

So your code looks like this:

```
group.setImmediate(true);
group.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() 
   {
       @Override
       public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) 
       {
            // Handle value change
       }
 });
```

The `setImmediate(true);` is important, otherwise the event is delayed until the focus is lost or another interaction happens.

Comment: Adding a ValueChangeListener to a component makes it implicitly immediate in latest 7 versions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info